# http post method passing null values to the server

Tags: android, http

```
         try 
         {

            url= new URL(ConstantsClass.VENDOR_FOLLOW + "?UID=" +android_id+"&URL='"+resultfinal+"'&device=android");


                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.flush();
                request.close();
                request.write("Hello!!!");

                String line = "";
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    sb.append(line + "&");
                }

                response = sb.toString();
                //response.getEntity().getContent();

                Log.i("Test", "updated response: " + response);



            }
         catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

            Log.i("Test", "**************url list********************" + url);
         tag_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent in=new Intent(context,LinkWebView.class);
                    in.putExtra("vendorUrl", resultfinal);
                    context.startActivity(in);      
                    //postData();
                }
            });
             }

    tag_text.setTextSize(16);
    return view;

}
```

Hi i am new to android and I am trying to pass values from the url to the server but i am getting null values passed on the server side. Update response is giving null. My server side values dont give any values to me. I need to pass the url, android_id and device from the url that is given above. I tried the httpclient also but it gives me null values in that as well.

Comment: check that you got all the value correctly before passing to the URL.BTW what "resultfinal" contains??

Comment: resultfinal has a url that i am passing. And i have printed this url value on toast and it gives me all the values correctly

Comment: what is android_id a number or a string?

Comment: android_id is a string that fetches the android_id of the system

Comment: Your mistake will be in **" +android_id+"** you will have to add single ('') outside ("")

Comment: It still is the same no values go

Comment: is they always send multiple data to server ?

Comment: NO it send once but for my url its sending data 3 times

Comment: Sorry but yes if you send 2 request it gives 6 records in all

Comment: ok devika , response body having 3 times records it mean server is sending multiple time. so concern your service developer and once print response data on server page so he/she find the proper solution.  hope you get my point. just tell him to print that response on same or other page so you can trace easily. ok

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you should try below code its running very well for me.

```
   // ADD YOUR REQUEST DATA HERE  (you can pass number of variable).
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Your_var_1", value));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Your_var_2", value));
```

Now establish your web connection like

## (1) Sending simple string to server

```
    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("your url only ex:www.google.com/abc");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    } catch (Exception e) 
    {   
        Log.e("Loading Runnable Error in http connection  :", e.toString());
    }
```

## (2) Send JSON Encode string to server

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
HttpResponse response;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

try {
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);
json.put("user_name", "chintan");
json.put("password", "khetiya");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity( json.toString());  
se.setContentType(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
post.setEntity(se);
response = client.execute(post);

 /*Checking response */
if(response!=null){
is = response.getEntity().getContent(); //Get the data in the entity
 }

} catch(Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
createDialog("Error", "Cannot Estabilish Connection");
}
```

## Response will same in both case

```
try 
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {   
        Log.e("Loading Runnable Error converting result :", e.toString());
    }
```

Now at the end result contain whole output string now its depend on you how you will read your data. using json or else. i am doing using json so put example code of it may be helpful to you.

```
JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);// its a string var which contain output. 
        my_output_one = json_data.getString("var_1"); // its your response var form web.
        my_output_two = json_data.getString("var_2");
```

Now its over you have two variable which having any kind of value and use any were.

Now this will helpful to you. if you have any query let me know.

Comment: Hi chintan i have tried doing this as well it still gives null values only

Comment: When i put a Toast to print url i gives me correct values all the values are correct.

Comment: php i have its log file with me but it gives me null values on the server side

Comment: yes but i need to fetch the pararmeter passing and send those parameters to the server currently i can go to the jsp page as well.

Comment: so in your postData() that send the var to web and retrieve the response according to request. so tell me that your all 4 var having a value or any null ?

Comment: that i know before that you directly pass argu in url . at that time your argu contain any value ? that i want to know. did you get my point. i want to check that if there are no any value at sending time then it will not response. and if that having a value it mean that sending request but at service side you have to concern with your service developer and handle . hope you got my concept.

Comment: its my pleasure.remind me if any other query i will try to help you.

Comment: you should use EntityUtils.toString, rather than reinventing reading a string from a stream.

Comment: @njzk2 i think you are talking about buffer ? can you suggest me how is it ?

Comment: you can replace ~10 lines of reading from an inputstream (creating the bufferedthing, readlines ...) by a single : `result = EntityUtils.toString(entity)`

Comment: my last syntax is entity.getContent(); and that i have to add in your syntax ?is it ?

Answer (score 1):

Please call the flush after write and close the stream in finally block. Check out the following code:

```
   try 
         {

            url= new URL(ConstantsClass.VENDOR_FOLLOW + "?UID=" +android_id+"&URL='"+resultfinal+"'&device=android");


                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
                request.write("Hello!!!");

                request.flush();


                String line = "";
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);

                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null) {
                    sb.append(line + "&");
                }

                response = sb.toString();
                //response.getEntity().getContent();

                Log.i("Test", "updated response: " + response);



            }
         catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }

            Log.i("Test", "**************url list********************" + url);
         tag_text.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent in=new Intent(context,LinkWebView.class);
                    in.putExtra("vendorUrl", resultfinal);
                    context.startActivity(in);      
                    //postData();
                }
            });
             }

    tag_text.setTextSize(16);
    return view;

}finally{
              try{
                request.close();
              }catch(Exception e){}
 }
```

Comment: No its still giving me null values only

Comment: Please try some rest tool to check that the request that you are sending is right and the server is sending some response. You can use following rest plug in to test that: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo