# HTTPURLConnection Getoutputstream Hanging

Tags: java, android, post, android-emulator

I am writing a java code to send POST request to a URL but it is getting hanged on the line indicated by bold. I am running this on android emulator

```
URL url = new URL("htt
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
OutputStream urlc = connection.getOutputStream(); //line on which code is getting hanged
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(urlc);
writer.write("message");
writer.close();
```

I am also able to run internet on emulator browser. That is I have checked that internet is working.

Comment: have you add internet permission in this project ?

Comment: Maybe you need to pass a proxy? so you need to first do something like this ? `System.setProperty("http.ProxyHost", "some.proxy");
                      System.setProperty("http.ProxyPort", "1080");`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, my mistake was that I set too big timeout(120 seconds).
Bigger timeout makes the HttpUrlConnection to wait more time before consuming each line. When I decreased it to 20 seconds it worked much faster.

before the change - waiting time of 4-5 seconds
after the change - only 0.5-1.5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134019/http-post-method-passing-null-values-to-the-server/13134287#13134287) is my one of the answer will help you and guide you on right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You have to enable billing of your application.

If billing is not enabled, the native (`HttpURLConnection`) in Java 8 environment won't work.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests

> When your app runs in Java 8 using default behavior, you must **enable your application for billing**, or you will get the following exceptions:
>
> - java.net.UnknownHostException
> - java.net.SocketTimeoutException
> - java.io.IOException

The other option is to use the legancy `urlfetch`, however, then you will encounter additional problems, like this:

[Got "DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential" if using Objectify 6.0 and <url-stream-handler> at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51976220/got-datastoreexception-request-is-missing-required-authentication-credential)