# Got "DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential" if using Objectify 6.0 and <url-stream-handler> at the same time

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

On an App Engine application, deployed on standard environment with java 8 activated, I get the exception below if I use both Objectify 6.0 AND the tag `<url-stream-handler>urlfetch</url-stream-handler>` in the appengine-web.xml file.

```
com.google.cloud.datastore.DatastoreException: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
```

Any idea how I can bypass that?

Things get back to normal if I remove the urlfetch tag (and activate the billing) or if I downgrade Objectify to v5.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what you're running into is one of the differences between the Java 7 and the Java 8 Standard Environments. There are substantial benefits to avoiding the `urlfetch` path, as [Issuing HTTP(S) Requests](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/issue-requests) notes (e.g. HTTP/2). In particular, the metadata server, which does automatic authentication for the Google Cloud SDKs when running on App Engine, isn't reachable using `urlfetch` (see that page).

I think your best option here is probably to enable billing, if you're comfortable with that. From the docs page:

> Despite the requirement to enable your application for billing, your app won't incur any more cost than the same application running on Java 7.

If you'd still like to give `urlfetch` a try, I think the error you're encountering can be fixed by manually supplying credentials (e.g. bundling them in your app), but that won't be as secure or performant.

Comment: Thanks for that, indeed the metadata server does not support the urlfetch service. Do you have any documentation mentioning that the metadata server does authentication for the Google Cloud SDKs (in particular the Datastore SDK)?

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to use the

```
<appengine-web-app>
   <url-stream-handler>native</url-stream-handler>
<appengine-web-app>
```

and enable **billing**. Without billing you can only use the legacy `urlfetch` and you have to face all these problems.

Answer (score 0):

you can set credentials explicitly, like it is shown in the example below:

```
            Resource credentialsCyberpower = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:yourservice-datastore-access.json");


            GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(credentialsCyberpower.getInputStream())
                  .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
            DatastoreOptions options =
                    DatastoreOptions.newBuilder().setProjectId("XXXXXX").setCredentials(credentials).build();
            Datastore datastore = options.getService();
            ObjectifyService.init(new ObjectifyFactory(datastore));
```

generate `yourservice-datastore-access.json` in IAM service accounts. working with Objectify 6.0.5