# trying to get array from php and store it in java,android

Tags: php, android, arrays, string

ive got a php file that connect to database and fetches data, now i want this data to be sent to my java code and be stored as an array, for connecting to php and retriving results i am using **AsyncHttpClient**
now in *AsyncHttpClient* their is a func **onSucess** that takes a string value as its parameter, soo anything coming from php is stored as string. i want it to be array..
 please suggest me a way, either to get an array instead of string
following is my code.

```
 public void func3(View view)throws Exception
{
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
    rp.put("pLat", "select * from iwmp_state");
    client.post("http://10.0.2.2/conc2.php", rp, newAsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        public final void onSuccess(Array response) {
            // handle your response here
            //tx.setText(response.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable e, String response) {
            // something went wrong
            tx.setText(response.toString());
        }               
    });
}
```

and ive got a php file which echos an array *$row*

```
<?php
 // attempt a connection
 $dbh = pg_connect("host=10.22.35.11 dbname=iwmp_dev2 user=postgres "); 
 if (!$dbh) {
     die("Error in connection: " . pg_last_error());
 }       

 // execute query
 $sql = $_POST['pLat'];
 $result = pg_query($dbh, $sql);
 if (!$result) {
     die("Error in SQL query: " . pg_last_error());
 }       
$array = array();
 // iterate over result set
 // print each row
 while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;
echo $row[0];
 }       

 // free memory
 pg_free_result($result);       

 // close connection
 pg_close($dbh);
 ?>
```

what php echos is array and what onSuccess takes as parameter is string. what to do!

Comment: where is response ? get that in jason and add in to list

Comment: JSON  - is there no other way

Comment: JSON is a standard way to encode data in php.you can send via ksop , xmletc

Comment: please post an example if possible. thank you. and response is jst a string. ive got no idea wht internal working is goin on inside onSuccess .. plz help sir. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it, what we can do is to use a **IMPLODE** func in our php, and add (,) after every array value
and then let it be passed as string. 
after getting it in java code use. *split(",")* func of String and store them in an array.

working fine for me. no json needed :P

Answer (score 5):

Here, i am just showing simple demo.You have to update as per your requirement.

## PHP Side

Creating simple `PHP Array` , For more detail [click here](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

```
<?php
$cars=array("Volvo","BMW","Toyota");
$arrlength=count($cars);

for($x=0;$x<$arrlength;$x++)
  {
  echo $cars[$x];
  echo "<br>";
  }
 echo json_encode($cars); 
 exit;
?>
```

## Android Side

**Now How to read PHP array inside in android ?**

```
String String_Response = ""; // this is your web response
```

Create a `ArrayList`.

```
    ArrayList<String> User_List = new ArrayList<String>();


                  try
              {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(String_Response);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++)
            {
                       JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);                                                        
               User_List.add(json_data.getString("your_json_obj"));
            }

               } 
                  catch (Exception e)
              {
            Log.e(TAG, "" + e);
               }
```

Also check out below link in that you will get more idea how to send and receive data from android to php.

[Android + PHP Communication Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134019/http-post-method-passing-null-values-to-the-server/13134287#13134287)

Comment: sir thanks for this example. it worked for me with your exam also.. now ive got json too.. thnx.. before this i did the same using IMPLODE AND SPLIT().. but thanx for this one.

Comment: any time.i will always ready to help.please accept the answer if its good for you

Comment: please tell me how to accept the ans and how to vote up an ans. also in the above code wat does "your_json_obj" imples, is it the string_response.. the one in which the json object is being stored when cuming from php..?

Comment: `your_json_obj` is your `JSON_TAG` which is assign to read keyword.you will find make simple web service. so you will get idea.For accept the answer you just have to click on right arrow , so that will change as green and clcik ` ^ ` for upvote

Comment: Yet,you haven't accept the answer,please do so good for other fresher can

Comment: thnk you for dis info sir, n to accept your ans i need repo of  15+, i only have repo of 14 .. for nw. :P

Comment: @chintan.. please see one of my ques.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353561/java-net-socketexceptionoperation-time-out-when-running-app-on-real-device

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for me to understand what you wish to achieve, but perhaps I can help a little with:
Implode your php array into a string (http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) then at least you can see what you are returning and perhaps re-process it client side?

Comment: got it, what we can do is to use a **IMPLODE** func in our php, and add (,) after every array value
and then let it be passed as string. 
after getting it in java code use. *split(",")* func of String and store them in an array.

working fine for me. no json needed :P