# httpget android wcf error

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

```
         HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

         String URL = "http://192.168.2.22:1099/Service1.svc/test";

         try
         {
            String setServerString = "";
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            setServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);
            lblStatus.setText(setServerString);
         }
         catch(Exception ex)
         {
           lblStatus.setText("Fail!");
         }
```

when we call the url it returns a string and is set to lblStatus.
This code is working fine in v2.3.* but not working in v4.0.
i'm able to get the string in v2.3.* versions but not in v4.0.

Comment: [See This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13134019/http-post-method-passing-null-values-to-the-server/13134287#13134287) & [This](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/)

Comment: @chintankhetiya, i'm not posting any data. I'm just calling a method which returns a string.

Comment: okay then no need to pass params , just call `URL` and get response.

Comment: is der any sample code. bcoz i'm new to android. i just started using httpget.

Comment: yeah, in blog there is github link, you can download form there

Comment: [check out here](http://chintankhetiya.wordpress.com/2013/05/27/83/)

Comment: what does "not work in 4.0" mean?

Comment: @blackbelt its not working in Android 4.2 Jelly Bean (API level 17)

Comment: you should get the NetworkOnMainTreadException

Comment: @blackbelt yep. what should i do to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you are getting the NetworkOnMainTreadException. This exception has been introduced with HoneyComb and it is raised when an attempt of run a network operation on the UI Thread is made.

If you want to overcame it you have to use an AsyncTask. Read the [android painless threading](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2009/05/painless-threading.html) guide